# Pandas adding decimal points when using read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with some csv files and using pandas to turn them into a dataframe. After that, I use an input to find values to delete

I'm hung up on one small issue: for some columns it's adding ".o" to the values in the column. It only does this in columns with numbers, so I'm guessing it's reading the column as a float. How do I prevent this from happening?

The part that really confuses me is that it only happens in a few columns, so I can't quite figure out a pattern. I need to chop off the ".0" so I can re-import it, and I feel like it would be easiest to prevent it from happening in the first place.

Thanks!

Here's a sample of my code:

```
clientid = int(input('What client ID needs to be deleted?'))

df1 = pd.read_csv('Client.csv')
clientclean = df1.loc[df1['PersonalID'] != clientid]
clientclean.to_csv('Client.csv', index=None)
```

Ideally, I'd like all of the values to be the same as the original csv file, but without the rows with the clientid from the user input.

The part that really confuses me is that it only happens in a few columns, so I can't quite figure out a pattern. I need to chop off the ".0" so I can re-import it, and I feel like it would be easiest to prevent it from happening in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a string `".o"`, or is it just importing as a float, decimal `.0`? It's unclear in your description

Comment: Maybe using the dtype parameter of the read_csv function will be enough to settle this? dtype={'PersonalID':np.int32}

Comment: The underlying issue is that there is no `np.NaN` support for integers, so if you have a column with numbers and missing values they are cast to a float and `12345` becomes `12345.0`. Small integers can be represented perfectly with `float64` so you do not need to worry about inaccuracies with floating point equality comparisons.

Comment: It's a float. So for example, in one column a value is "99," but after running it through the code it's converted to "99.0"

Answer (score 1):

If PersonalID if the header of the problematic column, try this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('Client.csv', dtype={'PersonalID':np.int32})
```

Edit:
As there are no NaN value for integer.
You can try this on each problematic colums:

```
df1[col] = df1[col].fillna(-9999) # or 0 or any value you want here
df1[col] = df1[col].astype(int)
```

Comment: likely needs to be cast to `object` as you cant have an `int32` column with missing values.

Comment: It's actually not the PersonalID column. I first noticed it two other columns, both integers. Null values do happen in those columns, but you're right, ever client must have a clientid.

Comment: If every client had a `ClientID` then `pandas` would downcast the column to an integer when it reads it in. The only reason it exists as a float is because it cannot cast the column to an integer, but the column has all numeric types (and missing) values, which is safely cast to `float`

Comment: If so, do you want to keep the na values?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to keep the na vallues. I'm wondering if it would be easiest to use .astype(object) to change all of the collums to objects, and make sure I don't miss anything.

Comment: Check my edit, maybe it's be something you could do if you really want integer.

Comment: And if you really want to keep the NaN values as NaN and not something else, the object type is wnat you need

Comment: I tested it on a few, and that works! Is there a faster way to assign the data type? I'd like to just set it for all columns instead of manually specifying, since that will be tedious and time consuming.

Comment: If you want all columns to be int: df1.astype(int) should do. (Just don't specify the column and pandas will do it for all the dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You could go through each value, and if it is a number `x`, subtract `int(x)` from it, and if this difference is not 0.0, convert the number `x` to `int(x)`.  Or, if you're not dealing with any non-integers, you could just convert all values that are numbers to `int`s.

For an example of the latter (when your original data does not contain any non-integer numbers):

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    for c, x in enumerate(row):
        if isinstance(x, float):
            df1.iloc[index,c] = int(x)
```

For an example of the former (if you want to keep non-integer numbers as non-integer numbers, but want to guarantee that integer numbers stay as integers):

```
import numbers
import sys

for c, col in enumerate(df1.columns):
    foundNonInt = False
    for r, index in enumerate(df1.index):
        if isinstance(x, float):
            if (x - int(x) > sys.float_info.epsilon):
                foundNonInt = True
                    break
    if (foundNonInt==False):
        df1.iloc[:,c] = int(df1.iloc[:,c])
    else:
```

Note, the above method is not fool-proof: if by chance, a non-integer number column from the original data set contains non-integers that are all x.0000000, all the way to the last decimal place, this will fail.

Answer (score -1):

It was a datatype issue.

ALollz's comment lead me in the right direction. Pandas was assuming a data type of float, which added the decimal points.

I specified the datatype as object (from Akarius's comment) when using read_csv, which resolved the issue.

Comment: Would be nice if you could have showed the solution