# Dataframe column with object datatype unableto convert to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below values in my dataframe and the column datatype is "object"

```
df['Calc_id']

2345.0
4545.0
1234.0
NaN
Nan
1000.0
```

How do I remove decimals(.0) ?

What i have tried First is:

```
df['Calc_id'].astype(int)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Another trial:

```
df['Calc_id'].str.strip('.0')
```

This remove the decimal at the end but removes all trailing zeros such as for below example

If we have a value of 1000 then it converts to 1

How do I resolve this?

I expect the out of 1000.0 to be 1000, but eh actual output is 1
because of str.strip('.0')

How do I fix this?

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: help to self-help. make a loop over your column and try to convert them one by one to the int. I'm pretty sure it will become obvious for you what to do to overcome it once you know where it really trips.

Comment: It's because int doesn't have a NaN value.

Comment: About the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54132508/pandas-adding-decimal-points-when-using-read-csv/54132711)

Comment: if you can bear the pain replacing Nan to float and then do convert `Calc_id` the to int that's one way, IS that possible here?

Comment: @Raj, see  the answer, hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to replace your Nan or fill Nan then convert to int obj:

```
>>> df['Calc_id'].replace(np.nan, 0.0).astype(int)
0    2345
1    4545
2    1234
3       0
4       0
Name: Calc_id, dtype: int64
```

Or you can use fillna method first to convert then to zero in order to get int obj:

```
>>> df['Calc_id'].fillna(0).astype(int)
0    2345
1    4545
2    1234
3       0
4       0
Name: Calc_id, dtype: int64
```

Your Solution is:

As i see your intend is just to remove trailing `.0` then below will do the job.

**Edit:**

```
>>> df
   Calc_id
0   2345.0
1   4545.0
2   1234.0
3   1000.0
4   2000.0
5   3000.0
6      NaN
7      NaN
```

just use the word boundary ie `\b.0\b`  to exact replacement.

```
>>> df['Calc_id'].replace(r'(\b.0\b)', '', regex=True)
0    2345
1    4545
2    1234
3    1000
4    2000
5    3000
6     nan
7     nan
Name: Calc_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Something like what?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't complete the question what if I have the  values as  : 1000.0,2000.0,3000.0 Performing the str.strip('.0') will return me 1,2,3. But I need 1000,2000,3000

Comment: See my updated answer, then replace is better way not strip().

Comment: if the answer helps then you can upvote & accept the answer.

Comment: Says that TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex'

Comment: df_tradelevelWindown['Calc_id'].replace(r'(\b.0\b)', '', regex=True). This worked for me

Comment: that will do as you are just  replacing, i forgot that keeping earlier perview in mind to converting it further to int obj but as i said earlier solution will be replace.